# How to assign the value to JSON by giving INDEX also

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

How to assign the value to the JSON by providing the index for it..

see the following code,

```
var jsonVariable = [];
jsonVariable[10] = {1:10};
alert(jsonVariable.toSource());
```

For the above code the output is,
**`[,,,,,,,,,{1:10}]`**
The output i expect and i need is [10 : {1:10}]
How to code to bring the output as i expect... please help me briefly..

Comment: Why would you expect the element at index 0 to be changed when you do `jsonVariable[10]=...` ?

Comment: i need to display some error msg for its correct index eg:10

Comment: try this: `jsonVariable['10'] = {1:10};` ;-) Or better this: `jsonVariable = ['10':{1:10}];`

Comment: i need outpus as, **`[10 : {1:10}]`**

Comment: this would be an array with the property `10` which doen't work i guess. `{10: {1:10}}` would

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used index-operators (`[]`), which instanciate a `new array` and set the element at index 10 to `{1: 10}`. You actually wanted to use curly braces operators (`{}`) which instanciate a `new object` and ad a property `10: {1:10}` like that:

```
var jsonVariable = {};
jsonVariable[10] = {1:10};
alert(jsonVariable.toSource());
```

Setting members to an `array`, you can't simply skip some indices (begin at 10). All uninstaciated indices until yours will forcible be created.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify an array index that doesn't yet exist like `[10]`, all previously unfilled indices are created.  Just `.push()` it on.

```
var jsonVariable = [];
// A numeric property should be a string "1", though the browser will probably forgive you
// Just push the new object onto the array
jsonVariable.push({"1":10});
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonVariable));
// [{1:10}] exactly as you describe
```

If you need this particular object `{1:10}` to be present at `jsonVariable[10]`, make it an object `{}` rather than an array.

```
var jsonVariable = {};
jsonVariable["10"] = {"1": 10};
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonVariable));
// {"10":{"1":10}}
```

Comment: if i use push its added to zeroth index no as {10: {1:10}}

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is:

```
var jsonVariable = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var temp = {};
    temp[i] = {'Property' : "Data"}
    jsonVariable.push(temp);
}
console.log( JSON.stringify(jsonVariable));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var jsonVariable = []; 
jsonVariable[10] = {1:10};  
function isNotEmpty(element, index, array) {
  return array[index];
};
jsonVariable = jsonVariable.filter(isNotEmpty);

alert(jsonVariable.toSource());
```